# отображения одного сайта, по разному в разных браузерах

Tags: html

Сделал такой стиль для главной странице на сайте:

```
<style>
Body{
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#2c476d), to(#2685c9)) no-repeat;
FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma;
FONT-SIZE: 13px;
}

#news {
    position: absolute;
    left: 215px;
    top: 340px;

        border:1px solid black;
    background-color:#b16800;
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px orange;

    background-image:url(/img/news.jpg);

}
#news_last {

    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 400px;

    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: lightblue;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px lightblue;

}
#menu{
    position: absolute;
    right: 100px;
    top: 340px;

        border:1px solid black;
    background-color:#b16800;
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px orange;

    background-image:url(/img/menu.jpg);

}
#menu_last{

    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    top: 400px;

    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: lightblue;
    width:250px;
    height:500px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px lightblue;

}
#my_site{
    margin:60px auto;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:#b16800;
    width:1150px;
    height:250px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px orange;
    position:relative;
    background-image:url(/img/shapka.jpg);
}
A{ text-decoration: none;  }

A:hover, A:active {color: #001111; text-decoration:underline}

</style>
```

Смотрю страницу через гугл-хром, красота, а захожу через Оперу так галимо, что ужас , как это исправить, доскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ссылку на сайт можно, чтобы посмотреть, что коверкается.

Comment: poke-friends.ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш градиент написан на CSS3. Для разных браузеров разные коды.

Для Mozilla Firefox хак выглядит следующим образом.

```
-moz-linear-gradient(
    center bottom,
    rgb(182,43,53) 42%,
    rgb(219,69,80) 71%,
    rgb(255,97,112) 86%
)
```

А для браузеров на движке webkit (Safari, Chrome, Arora, Konqueror и др.), так.

```
-webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.42, rgb(182,43,53)),
    color-stop(0.71, rgb(219,69,80)),
    color-stop(0.86, rgb(255,97,112))
)
```

Comment: И для других дивов тоже самое. Для разных браузеров — разные стили.

Comment: А как пронюхать каким браузером пользуется пользователь?

Comment: Сделать стиль под разные браузеры. К примеру так: http://myvista.ru/dif_css_styles

Погугли. Много информации по этому поводу.

Comment: Лучше вообще отказаться от этого градиента, а сделать фон одним цветом. Куда лучше будет. И все браузеры понимают.